# Electron Node.js app does not execute Python script

Tags: python, node.js, electron

I am trying to get my python script executed in a packed electron app. It does not work for some reason, also the script is execute when using `npm start` to launch the program before packaging.

This is the complete content of my file `render.js` which calls the python script:

```
const actionButton = document.getElementById('actionButton');
actionButton.onclick = doStuff;

async function doStuff(){

    console.log('Doing JS stuff.')

    var path = require('path');
    var python = require('child_process').spawn('python', [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'py', 'main.py'), 'Hello', 'World']);
    python.stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString('utf8')));

    python.on('close', () => console.log('Did PY stuff, too.'))

}
```

And the result using `npm start` indicates everything works fine since the python reply is printed to the console:
[image: console log with npm start]

Launching the actual app shows a different (wrong) result. The Python reply is simply not printed. No errors. Also the path to the python script changed and points to the correct direction. I double checked at least five times by now:
[image: console log when launched as app]

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: maybe your python script did not write anything to stdout. Maybe listen on stderr as well? ```python.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});```

Comment: verify whether the script is running or whether the stdout is not being received. Maybe create a file or something from within the py script to check

Comment: Thank you! I just figured out the `stderr` contains data. So, your first comment answers my question. If you make it an answer I'm happy to accept. I'll have a look on how to solve the error myself :)

Comment: However, all my main.py contains is

Comment: ```import sys
print(f"Python reply: {sys.argv[1]} {sys.argv[2]}")
sys.stdout.flush()```

Comment: I don't understand why this causes an error one way and not the other ..

Comment: What error showed up in stderr?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226251/discussion-between-t348575-and-maxischl).